# unable to generate the hash for netbeans 8.2

Tags: sha256

I am unable to generate the hash for the netbeans 8.2 for Ubuntu 16.04
after I write the command:

```
ravi@Dell:~/Downloads$ sha256 netbeans-8.2-linux.sh 
mlockall: Cannot allocate memory
Warning: couldn't lock memory, are you root?
Enter passphrase:
```

Now what is this passphrase?
What should I do now?

Comment: Just enter passphrase (something you must type to generate a hashing. Example: "Donald Trump is a great goofy". After that, look what happens. Maybe is just a warning, not harmful

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you should have execute **`sha256sum`** which calculate the checksum.

```
sha256sum netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

I also found  [NetBeans 8.2 C / C ++ for Linux Xubuntu 16.04 64/32](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=iw&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpilonestefano.altervista.org%2Fnetbeans%2Fnetbeans82-linux-cpp.htm&edit-text=)  which specify:

> and **check its sha256 (from Terminal: `sha256sum path / filename`).**

---

See below the difference between `sha256` and `sha256sum`

> [man sha256sum](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/sha256sum.1.html) - compute and check SHA256 message digest 
>   [man sha256](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/sha256.1.html) - hashalot - read a passphrase and print a hash

Answer (score 2):

From `man sha256` `passphrase` is just used to produce the hashing any thing is fine.

```
DESCRIPTION
       hashalot is a small tool that reads a passphrase from standard input, hashes it using the given hash type, and
       prints the result to standard output.

       Warning: If you do not use the -x option, the hash is printed in binary. This may  wedge  your  terminal  set‐
       tings, or even force you to log out.

       This  is  not  a  general  purpose  hasher, only the first line is used, not even including the final newline.
       Thus, don't be surprised if the output seems to be different from other tools -- you'd have  to  hash  exactly
       the same string.
```

Answer (score 0):

it hashes from `std in`, so perhaps this would work:

```
cat netbeans-8.2-linux.sh  |sha256
```

However, you have another issue there, you must set the the memory allocation,
to get rid of the `mlockall` error.